# How to get inflow/outflow for every item from a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this list:

```
myList = [a, a, a, b, b, a, c, c, b, a]
```

I want to count the inflow and the outflow for every unique item.

Inflow for 'a' = number of appearances = 5
(when a transition ENTERS in 'a')

Outflow for 'a' = number of different characters after 'a' = 2
(when a transition EXITS from 'a' to another character)

For inflow I have this and it works:

```
myListDict = {}    
for item in myList:
    myListDict.setdefault(item, 0)
    myListDict[item] += 1
```

But I don't really know how to do this in a fast and elegant way for the outflow, on a single overall iteration, if possible.

Comment: In `myList = [a, a, a, b, a, c, a, b]` what is `outflow[a]` ? It is a bit ambigous in the current description

Comment: If the next element after 'a' is different, you count, so we have 1 (when a goes to b), 2 (when a goes to c) and 3 (when a goes to b). So outflow['a']=3

Comment: @DeepSpace I read as `a, b` and `a, c` with the final `a` not counting because there is no following letter

Comment: You are right. In my example, in the description, outflow['a']=2, because the last 'a' does not have a right neighbor letter. And in your example, outflow['a'] is 3, as stated previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate both inflow and outflow in one single pass, you could use this structure:

```
from collections import Counter

last_char = None

my_list = "aaabbaccba"

inflow = Counter()
outflow = Counter()

for char in my_list:
    inflow[char] += 1
    if last_char and char != last_char:
        outflow[last_char] += 1
    last_char = char


print(inflow)
print(outflow)
```

It outputs:

```
Counter({'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 2})
Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})
```

Note that with [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), you don't need `setdefault`.

Comment: This works, except the fact that the last element remains without outflow.
I update now my description.

Comment: @Marko: I updated the answer as well. One single pass and it calculates inflow and outflow at the same time.

Comment: I've tested it with my real data. Please have a look at the updated description.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Didn't noticed at first that 'S' was the last element and the outflow is 0. All clear now, thank you, Eric!

Comment: @Marko: You're welcome. And with `Counter`, you can still get a count for a non-existing key : `outflow['S']` outputs `0`

Answer (score 1):

I use `itertools.groupby` to eliminate identical successive items, then count the inflow transitions. For the outflow, we just have to substract 1 to the inflow count for the last item of the list.

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

myList = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a']

uniques = [key for key, g in groupby(myList)]  # ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a']
c = Counter(uniques)
inflow = dict(c)
c.update({myList[-1]: -1})  # No outflow for the last element
outflow = dict(c)

print(inflow)
# {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}

print(outflow)
# {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}
```

Comment: Looking at the comments under the question, it looks like you don't need the sets. Outflow for `'a'` in `'abab'` seems to be `2`.

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes, I've seen the comments after  answering... I started editing the answer, but there's not much to add to Chris Rands' and your answer, I think...

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the confusing part. Thank you for your edit, Thierry!

Comment: @Marko Well, that happens. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections.Counter` and `itertools.groupby`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

def in_out_flow(lst):
    in_flow = Counter(lst)
    out_flow = Counter(k for k, _ in groupby(lst))
    out_flow[lst[-1]] -= 1
    for k,v in in_flow.items():
      print('key: {}, in flow: {}, out flow: {}'.format(k, v, out_flow[k]))
```

Examples:

```
in_out_flow(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a'])
print('##')
in_out_flow(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'])
```

Outputs:

```
key: a, in flow: 5, out flow: 2
key: b, in flow: 3, out flow: 2
key: c, in flow: 2, out flow: 1
##
key: a, in flow: 5, out flow: 3
key: b, in flow: 2, out flow: 1
key: c, in flow: 1, out flow: 1
```

Comment: Got it, Chris! Thank you very much for your reply!